NewRelic with NextJS - alert application frontend errors via email
We have NewRelic integrated into our NextJS application (hosted in Vercel). I am able to see the error and other logs. But I was trying to get an alert when an application error occurs (frontend error where it displays a message).
I tried creating an Alert from the dashboard of NewRelic. But it is not firing. The query from there looks something like this:
SELECT count(*) as 'Errors' FROM JavaScriptError WHERE entityGuid IN ('MzIzNDg2NXxCUk9XU0VSfEXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX') FACET appName
I tried googling and also tried creating another alert. I used their "recommended" way. But still not alerting when a frontend occurs. The thing is, when a frontend error occurs, NextJS displays a message that there is an application error has occurred and prevents anything else to be viewed to the user. We want to immediately take a look at it and rectify it as soon as possible. That's why we are trying to implement the alert.
Any suggestions are highly appreciated.
